# How to pick a spring batch job to run based on file type

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-batch

I am using Spring Boot + Spring Batch(annotation), the application has 10 batch jobs configured for 10 different types of files. The file itself is pulled from AmazonS3. Can anyone guide me on how to programmatically run a batch job based on the type of file pulled from S3. Each of the 10 batch jobs runs just fine when the file is placed in the class path, not sure how to pick a job to run based on file type. Totally new to Spring boot and Spring batch, any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class FileTypeX1Configuration{
     private FileTypeX1PRocessor fileTypeX1PRocessor ;
     private FileTypeX1Writer fileTypeX1Writer ;

     .
     .
}

.
.
.
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class FileTypeX10Configuration{
     private FileTypeX10PRocessor fileTypeX10PRocessor ;
     private FileTypeX1oWriter fileTypeX10Writer ;

     .
     .
}
```

Comment: Each job add a spring batch cron so it will automatically executes and read based on resource type

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need to add `@EnableBatchProcessing` in one of your configuration classes. This is typically added on the main class of your Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SampleApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

Now regarding your conditional job launching, there are several ways to do that (like using Spring profiles, using a custom condition based on `@Conditional` to define your job beans, etc). But the most straight-forward way is doing in it the main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SampleApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
      JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
      
      File file = .. // get file
      // based on file type, run the required job:
      Job job = context.getBean("jobX", Job.class);
      jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
   }

}
```

You would need to set `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to prevent Spring Boot from running all jobs at your application startup.

If you can detect the file type outside of your app (in a shell script for example) you can tell Spring Boot which job should be run from your script with the property `spring.batch.job.names=jobX`.